# Specify Double Quotes for Thymeleaf's inline Javascript

Tags: thymeleaf, json-ld

I'm trying to add some Schema Markup to a site built with Thymeleaf. My first thought was to use the ld+json method:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" th:inline="javascript">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": /*[[ ${C:Location.street}]]*/,
      "addressLocality": /*[[ ${C:Location.city}]]*/,
      "addressRegion": /*[[ ${C:Location.state}]]*/,
      "postalCode": /*[[ ${C:Location.zipcode}]]*/
    },
}
</script>
```

But Thymeleaf outputs those strings in single quotes, which apparently doesn't validate as correct JSON when checking with https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Is it possible to tell Thymeleaf to use double quotes here? I can do the HTML microdata markup if all else fails but I'd prefer not to since it's not as pretty and modular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use text mode:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" th:inline="text">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "EmailMessage",
        "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "ViewAction",
            "url": "[[ @{${url}} ]]",
            "name": "[[ #{message.button.text} ]]"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Output:

```
<script type=3D"application/ld+json" xml:space=3D"preserve">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "EmailMessage",
        "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "ViewAction",
            "url": "https://watch-movies.com/watch",
            "name": "Watch movie"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: not working for me, I get:   "name": "'Watch movie'"

Comment: One problem with this solution is that aside from enclosing the string in single-quotes, thymeleaf is also escaping any single quotes in the string.  By switching to text mode, there is no escaping going on.  If the string contains any double quotes, now a parse error is introduced.

Comment: There's also a problem if the value is null, as you'll have `"null"` which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for people using `html.erb`

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EmailMessage",
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "url": <%= resource.photos.first(3).map(&:url) %>,
        "name": "some text"
      }
  }
</script>
```

Here instead of having something like `["url1", "url2", "url3"]` for the url field you will get `[&quote;url1&quote;, &quote;url2&quote; &quote;url3&quote;]`.

To get the desired result use `.to_json.html_safe`

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "url": <%= resource.photos.first(3).map(&:url).to_json.html_safe %>,
        "name": "some text"
    }
  }
</script>
```